# What's wrong with this QuickSort program?

Tags: c#, algorithm

I've written a QuickSort algorithm based off pseudo-code that I had been given.
I've been running through the outputs for about 4 hours now and I can't seem to find exactly why my algorithm starts to derail. This sort of collection logic is something I struggle with.

Anyway, whenever I run my program there's 3 possible results:

1. The list is organized and is 100% correct.
2. The list is 90% organized, one or two pairs of elements are off.
3. The list is never sorted and results in an infinite loop.

Given my results it leads me to believe that something has to do with the `index` variable I'm using. However, I can' figure out why or what's wrong with it.

Here's ALL of my code that I use for my QuickSort algorithm:

```
public void QuickSort(IList<int> list, int l, int r)
    {
        if (l>=r) return; 
        int index = Partition(list, l, r);
        Console.WriteLine("index: " + index);
        QuickSort(list, l, (index-1));
        QuickSort(list, (index+1), r);
    }

    public int Partition(IList<int> list, int l, int r)
    {
        int pivot = list[l];
        int i = l;
        int j = r + 1;
        do 
        {
            do { i++; } while(i < list.Count && list[i] < pivot);
            do { j--; } while(j > 0 && list[j] >= pivot);
            Swap(list, i, j);
        } while(i<j);
        Swap(list, i ,j);
        Swap(list, j, l);
        return j;
    }

    public void Swap(IList<int> list, int i, int j)
    {
        //Console.WriteLine("Swapping [i] " + list[i] + " with [j] " + list[j]);
        //PrintList(list, i, j, false);
        int temp = list[i];
        list[i] = list[j];
        list[j] = temp;
        //PrintList(list, j, i, true);

    }
```

PrintList is simply used to test my outputs.

Here is a sample input/output:

INPUT: 
[18,43,5,73,59,64,6,17,56,63]

OUTPUT: [5,6,18,17,43,59,56,63,64,73]

Comment: he he...  is this a homework problem?  what would your professor say?

Comment: It is a homework problem, but when we have an issue with our code our professors say "google it" -- and about 60% of the result are from this website anyway. So it's basically the same thing. In addition to that I have, as mentioned, been working on this for quite some time with zero progress and figure I'm missing something obvious. I've also done most of the work, I'm not asking anyone to do the algorithm for me, but rather help me debug what I currently have.

Comment: The algorithm is quit OK, you're asking about this implementation.

Comment: How did you post this?  I notice a `n-1` where there shouldn't be a `n`.

Comment: What is `n` in `Partition` and `Sort` in `QuickSort` ?

Comment: @Johannes, sorry, was a tongue in cheek response.  just joking with ya cause the only reason someone would be asking about quicksort would be because it was homework...  brought me back to my days in college :)

Comment: I think you should re-examine the `i<n-1` and `j>0` parts

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about `n` - that's the input size, so `n-1` translates to `list.count`. I edited my post for clarification. I use `i<n-1` and `j>0` to ensure I don't run off the list.

Comment: And Sort is QuickSort, I had renamed it after I copied it over and forgot to change the other two. Apologies. (Edited to match)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public int Partition(IList<int> list, int l, int r){
    int pivot = list[l];
    int i = l+1;
    int j = r;
    while(true){
        //{i,j| l< i,j <= r}
        while(i<=r && list[i] <  pivot)++i;
        while(j>l  && list[j] >= pivot)--j;
        if(i<j)
            Swap(list, i, j);
        else
            break;
    }
    Swap(list, l, j);
    return j;
}
```

Comment: And what should happen when `list[i] <=  pivot` ?

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you. But more importantly I'd like to know why? It seems to be doing almost exactly the same thing as mine.

Comment: @Johannes , One reason is the range of j and i. It must be passed between the l and r in the argument. Then, i and j increment or decrement  has case of over range . I think you can try to simulate on paper.

Comment: @Henk Holterman , Does my code has BUG? ex.{18,18,18},{18,18,29},{18,18,17,29} All case valid.

Answer (score 2):

One problem is in your partition method, where you have:

```
    int i = l;
    int j = r + 1;
    do 
    {
        do { i++; } while(i < list.Count && list[i] < pivot);
        do { j--; } while(j > 0 && list[j] >= pivot);
        Swap(list, i, j);
    } while(i<j);
```

If you enter with `l == 0`, then the first time through your loop you increment `i`, and the first item checked is `list[1]`. You probably want those `do` loops to be `while` loops.

Another problem is that you unconditionally swap `list[i]` and `list[j]` in your loop, even if `list[i] <= list[j]`. You probably should check before you do that swap.

That won't solve all your problems, but it'll point you in the right direction.